# Create and run docker image for Spring MVC

Tags: spring, windows, spring-mvc, docker, tomcat

I want deploy my spring mvc application with rest to docker. I created tomcat based image with this dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.31-jre8
ADD  /target/my-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

and my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(path="", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String[] findAll() {
        return new String[] {"sdfsdsdf", "sfsdfsff", "fdsfsfsfdfffdsfsdf"};
    }
}
```

When I run my app from local Tomcat with my IDE, it works and when I go to localhost:8080 I got controller response, but now when I create image and run it when I go to localhost:8080 in browser I can see tomcat homepage, not my endpoint response. Can you tell me what I do wrong?

Here is command which I use to create and run image:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

and

```
docker run -d  -p 8080:8080  --name mydockerapp myapp
```

I am using Win10. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Are you sure that you typed the correct URL? Compare with the URL in your IDE) It looks like you just forgot enter app name in path)

Comment: @AlexanderPolozov hi, thanks for effort but I don't understand how path? can you be more specific or give me example? I am little newbie with docker

Comment: i mean name of your app in URL, nothing to do with the docker. (http://localhost:8080/yourAppName/.......)

Comment: @AlexanderPolozov I cannot try your advice because when I tried run it again I got this error: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mydockerapp (43bf7e856fa167f25518706bcc8075cdc16a8f59ca9b1a75647673f6706b6185): Error starting userland proxy:
 mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8080:tcp:172.17.0.2:8080: input/output error. :/

Comment: @AlexanderPolozov Ok I solve my previous problem with restart docker, I again go to localhost where I find tomcat homepage and after changing url to http://localhost:8080/mydockerapp  I got 404 error

Comment: try localhost:8080/my-app/ since your war file is named my-app.war

Comment: If you want your app to be available on `http://localhost:8080/`, you'll need to change the `COPY` command to `COPY /target/my-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war`.

Comment: @C-Shark still same result

Comment: @gesellix hi, I got same result as well

Comment: mydockerapp is the name of your container, the name of your application is the name of the .war archive. This is completely independent of the docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are deploying your web app to the root context path in the local tomcat. However, the tomcat in the docker images already have a welcome page app deployed to the root context path.

What you need to do is to delete this welcome page app and rename your app to `ROOT.war` , then deploy it.

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.31-jre8
RUN rm -rvf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
ADD  /target/my-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: now I have not welcome page either, when I go to localhost:8080 I got 404 error

Comment: Are you sure you really copy your war to the container or the war is packaged correctly  ? You can verify it by "ls" the tomcat 's webapps folder (e.g. `docker exec -ti mydockerapp ls -ltr /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT`). Check if the app is packaged properly by navigating this folder.

Comment: I tried your command and I got this result:
-rw-r----- 1 root root   27 Jun 13 14:35 package-lock.json
drwxr-x--- 4 root root 4096 Jun 13 19:24 WEB-INF
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Jun 13 19:24 node
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Jun 13 19:24 META-INF

Comment: 1. Check the log to see if the app start successfully  (`docker logs mydockerapp`) 2. Check the `web.xml` to verify the url path of the spring mvc 's `DispatcherServlet`

Comment: thank you, I got bug in my project, your solution works now :)